# Metadata problem

Tags: metadata

I have a photograph which displays time taken and camera model etc. But looking further at the properties and under "file", there is no date created or modified date. But there is a date of when it was taken under "origin"? Any help will be appreciated.
ThankyouIam a bit confused as to why there is no date under the "file"

Comment: Can you please edit this question so the title describes the specific issue? Thank you.

Comment: What operating system and file system? What image/exif viewer? Some date properties are part of the underlying file system and may not be displayed by all image viewers.

Comment: vtc b/c "looking further at the properties and under 'file'" – This is a *non-photographic* problem related to the file system or operating system.

Answer (score 1):

Image formats such as JPEG can contain "metadata" that is added to the file by the camera when the picture is stored. This contains information such a date/time taken, but also camera brand/model, lens, focal length, aperture, shutter speed, orientation, GPS coordinates (if the camera/phone supports this) and a thumbnail images (all cameras do this). These data are known as "EXIF" (because they are defined by an EXIF standard).

There are many utilities to handle them. In the Windows file explorer, you can set columns to display some of these fields (right click in the columns header, and click `More...` at the bottom of the menu).

Comment: The problem doesn't appear to be embedded metadata, but the fact that there is no OS time stamps.  OP says that the data doesn't appear under the "FILE" section of Properties->Details.  Which shouldn't be possible on a local drive, I would think.  Unless the file is on some sort of network or something similar maybe?